# Status, Patent No. 4,442,710

Tags: us4442710

Has this 1984 patent expired or was it renewed? I am considering referencing it. If it has expired, I will reference the authors.

Comment: The people listed on a patent are properly - inventors  - not authors.

Answer (score 2):

In 1984, patents expired 17 years from the grant date. This patent would have expired long ago. Patents are not renewable.